# Using Linq to Get Lat/Lon from Bing Maps REST Service

Tags: xml, linq-to-xml, bing-maps, xelement

I'm calling the Bing Maps Service to return some XML here:

http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/Encoded_Address?o=xml&key=Maps_Key

For the life of me, I can't seem to get the Longitude and Latitude using Linq! It always returns `null`. Here's the code I'm using (I've used Atlanta, GA as an example):

```
xml = XElement.Load(url); // url is as above
var locations = from l in xml.Descendants( "Location" )
                        select l;
// Output to Test    
foreach(var location in xml.Descendants("Location")){
  // We NEVER get in here.
  Console.WriteLine( "Lat: "  + location.Descendants("Latitude").First().Value );
  Console.WriteLine( "Long: " + location.Descendants("Longitude").First().Value);
  Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I've also tried adding a namespace:

```
XNamespace xn = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1";
xml.Descendants(xn + "Location"))
```

**But NO go. What am I doing wrong???**

Here's the relevant XML fragment (only relevant parts are here)

```
<Response xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1">
  <ResourceSets>
    <ResourceSet>
      <EstimatedTotal>1</EstimatedTotal>
      <Resources>
        <Location>
          <Name>Atlanta, GA</Name>
          <Point>
            <Latitude>33.748315</Latitude>
            <Longitude>-84.39111</Longitude>
          </Point>
          <!-- other stuff here -->
        </Location>
      </Resources>
    </ResourceSet>
  </ResourceSets>
</Response>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to include namespace in all places as shown below.

```
// Output to Test    
foreach(var location in xml.Descendants(xn +"Location")){
  // NOW WE GET IN HERE.
  Console.WriteLine( "Lat: "  + location.Descendants(xn +"Latitude").First().Value );
  Console.WriteLine( "Long: " + location.Descendants(xn + "Longitude").First().Value);
  Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: I've tried that. No dice. There are three namespaces on the XML file... some with XSI and XSD schemas... Do those matter?

Comment: @Atømix I tried **[this](http://pastie.org/2063114)** and it prints Lat and long.

Comment: ARGH! You're right. I think my XML was messed up. I copied the XML again and it worked. Probably the nested quotes. Thanks a bunch!